# Iterate over dictionary values list in C# to check for specific key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I would like to iterate over dictionary values which is a list of strings in C# to check for all keys

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> csvList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I want to check each key(string) in csvList and check if it exists in any values(List)

```
foreach(var events in csvList)
{
   foreach(var action in csvList.Values) // But I want to loop through all the lists in dictionary, not just the list of event key
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If your iterating a dictionary then your using your dictionary wrong. The whole point of a dictionary is to stop you having to iterate

Comment: that said you just need an inner loop `foreach(var val in action)`

Comment: if you are going to iterate, better create an object, it is way easier

Comment: @Liam What is the best data structure to use if we want to have a set of values for each string. For example: New York - > Boston, Phil
So in this instance, I am using a dictionary of string and List. How do you do it and what is the best data structure in this instance then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(var events in csvList)
{
   foreach(var action in csvList.Values) 
    {
       if (action.Contains(events.Key)) //Just use this, there is no point to iterate the list as you can use contains method
    }
}
```

Comment: You realise `Contains` will iterate the list right?

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of strange but let's try to work through it. We don't usually want to iterate the keys of a dictionary. The reason to use one is we want to get the values very quickly if we already know the key.

In the spirit of answering the question, to iterate over a Dictionary's keys you have to use the `Keys` property. Note that nothing about the order of this collection is guaranteed.

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
d.Add("one", 1);
d.Add("two", 2);

foreach (var k in d.Keys) {
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

But I think maybe you had a problem and chose a Dictionary as the solution, then came here when that didn't work. What if the Dictionary isn't the problem?

It sounds like you have several `List<string>` instances and you're interested in if a particular list contains a particular string. Or maybe you want to know, "Which lists contain which string?" We can answer that with a dictionary structured slightly differently. I'm going to use arrays instead of lists because it's easier to type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    private static void AddWord(Dictionary<string, List<int>> d, string word, int index) {
        if (!d.ContainsKey(word)) {
            d.Add(word, new List<int>());   
        }

        d[word].Add(index);
    }

    private static List<int> GetIndexesForWord(Dictionary<string, List<int>> d, string word) {
        if (!d.ContainsKey(word)) {
            return new List<int>();
        } else {
            return d[word];
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var stringsToFind = new[] { "one", "five", "seven" };

        var listsToTest = new[] {
            new[] { "two", "three", "four", "five" },
            new[] { "one", "two", "seven" },
            new[] { "one", "five", "seven" }
        };

        // Build a lookup that knows which words appear in which lists, even
        // if we don't care about those words.
        var keyToIndexes = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        for (var listIndex = 0; listIndex < listsToTest.GetLength(0); listIndex++) {
            var listToTest = listsToTest[listIndex];
            foreach (var word in listToTest) {
                AddWord(keyToIndexes, word, listIndex);
            }
        }

        // Report which lists have the target words.
        foreach (var target in stringsToFind) {
            Console.WriteLine("Lists with '{0}':", target);
            var indices = GetIndexesForWord(keyToIndexes, target);
            if (indices.Count == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("  <none>");
            } else {
                var message = string.Join(", ", indices);
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}", message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```